# "No implicit conversion between type A and type B" error when using ternary operator

Tags: c#

Why am I not allowed to do this:

```
private Base Property => m_IsAbsolute ? new A() : new B();
```

> Compiler complains about 'No implicit conversion between A and B

I can fix that by casting `B` to `Base`, but why on earth would I need to do that?

While I am allowed to do this:

```
private Base Property2
{
    get
    {
        if (m_IsAbsolute)
        {
            return new A();
        }
        return new B();
    }
}
```

For reference the classes used in above example:

```
class Base
{
}

class A : Base
{
}

class B : Base
{        
}
```

Comment: That is allowed in C# 9 AFAIK; it wasn't before, because on the moment parser sees `condition ? new A()` it implicitly types the expression as `A` even if hierarchy contains common superclass for both branches. And yes, it looks like mistake in design

Comment: @АндрейСаяпин - no, it doesn't assume `A`. It considers both sides of the `:` equally but it does want to pick *one* of the two actual types.

Comment: That's not quite true. C# 9 still refuses to go looking for a common base type between `A` and `B`, but it will target-type the expression: so `var x = true ? new A() : new B()` doesn't work in C# 9, but `Base x = true ? new A() : new B()` does. [See here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+ABATARgFgAoE7AZgAI9KBhSgbxMpequwBZKBZACgEpGzViIBuEBJQAelALyUYCAK5xKAfkoA7OAHdKAQQGUQW3ZQBCAgNzCWAXxIPiIsrgvQ4JJsSeuDx9yhPYm9fYhpzAPMPLxEXHyA===)